# telerik window does not show

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

On page I write telerik window:

```
<telerik:RadWindow ID="DictionaryWindow" runat="server"></telerik:RadWindow>
```

on this page I run javascript when user click on button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getWindow() { return document.getElementById("<%= DictionaryWindow.ClientID %>"); }

var oWin = getWindow();
    if (oWin != null) {            
        oWin.setUrl("WebForm1.aspx");
        oWin.set_width(800);
        oWin.set_height(800);
        oWin.Show();
        oWin.Center();

    }
</script>
```

an error apears: Object doesn't support this property or method.
I find this javascript on the net like example. 
Is this the correct way to get telerik window to show? Can I get the window to appear some another way?

Comment: Go accept some answers to your previous questions first.

Comment: in which line are you getting this error?

Comment: on line: oWin.setUrl("WebForm1.aspx");   I watch runtime work and it sems that object oWin haven't methods setUrl() and others to.

Comment: Ok I find problem: the function that get the telerik windo on page: 

    function getWindow() { return document.getElementById("<%= DictionaryWindow.ClientID %>"); }

actually incorrect! It must be:

    function getWindow() { return $find("<%= DictionaryWindow.ClientID %>"); }

I do not fully understand why, but in thes way object oWin have all require methods.

Comment: I agree with @Kon. Go accept answers on some of the questions you've asked in the past. It will help you questions in the future be answered in a timely fashion. Also, answering your own question in the comments is not the proper way to do things. Either post the answer yourself or accept an answer below that is correct (like mine).

Answer (score 0):

I would use the RadWindowManager to access your windows:

```
function UseRadWindow()
{
   var oManager = GetRadWindowManager();
   var oWnd = oManager.GetWindowByName("DictionaryWindow");
   oWnd.setUrl("WebForm1.aspx");        
   oWnd.SetWidth(800);
   oWnd.SetHeight(800);
   oWnd.Show();
   oWnd.Center();
}
```

You could also do it by accessing the window directly:

```
function UseRadWindow()
{
   var oWnd = $find("<%= DictionaryWindow.ClientID %>"); 
   oWnd.setUrl("WebForm1.aspx");        
   oWnd.SetWidth(800);
   oWnd.SetHeight(800);
   oWnd.Show();
   oWnd.Center();
}
```

Take a look at their client-side API docs:

[Telerik RadWindowManager Client-Side API](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/window/radwindowobjectclientside.html)

Answer (score -1):

getElementById will return the element, while in order to get access to the control's client API, you need to get a reference to its object - that is why you need to use $find().

Answer (score -2):

Javascript is a case-sensitive language. The telerik controls use (mostly) camel-casing for their javascript methods. According to the documentation, you probably want:

oWin.show();

oWin.center();

Comment: This is incorrect. Take a look at their API docs: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/window/radwindowobjectclientside.html